# XCode 4 vs. Xcode - 5 dependence and linking

Tags: c++, xcode

I had a c++ project in Xcode 4.6.3 that was made up of several libraries, called base, level1, and level2 for this example. level2 depended on level1 and base, level1 depended on base, and base had no dependencies. In my project settings the only relationships I explicitly added were these dependencies (the target dependencies sections of the Build Phases settings), and XCode knew to link against the depended libraries during the build. However, after upgrading to XCode 5, this linking stopped working. Now, I need to explicitly add the libraries to BOTH the target dependencies section, and the link binary with libraries section.

Is this behavior a bug or simply a change in configuration details? If it is the latter, when would you want to depend on a library but not link against it?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't say I've noticed a change in behaviour.  I always use an Xcode Workspace however.

Comment: Xcode 4+'s "Find Implicit Dependencies" functionality has never been reliable for me, especially as dependency complexity increases. I mean, yes, it can figure it out reliably in some cases, but the feature has never been able to reliably build out my projects. Defining dependencies using explicit build and link steps may be necessary. I always configure them explicitly and disable "Find Implicit Dependencies".